# A field array with object ids returns automatically sorted unintentionally

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb

I have a query which returns an array of object ids sorted by their id instead of the order that i put them in the array. Why is that happening? i don't have anything in the code related to the sort option, Moreover it does return like i wanted in the backend but in the front it returns sorted. why is that?

Edit:

i use graphql-compose-mongoose:

this is the part of the schema :

```
  sections: {
type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId],
ref: "Sections",
default: [],
```

},

and this is the relation:

```
  resolver: () => SectionTC.getResolver("findByIds"),
  prepareArgs: {
    _ids: (source: Questionnaire) => source.sections,
  },
  projection: {
    sections: true,
  },
```

so the array is like:

```
63398d312940b0d8da89e1c1
62e7d0f168db432caf5c8ff7
62e7d11b68db432caf5c8ff8
63398d6c2940b0d8da89e1c8
```

but when i populate them, they return in a sorted order which i cannot get to disable.

Comment: I think we need more information to be able to help. What libraries (and versions) are you using for the "backend" where the information is correct? Same question for the frontend where the results are incorrect.  How are the two systems communicating the information between one another?

Comment: yeah, i added more information. Thanks!